# "Private" permission setting in readthedocs.org - how does it work?

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm aware RTD has a [commercial version](http://readthedocs.com) which offers Private settings.

With that in mind, why is there a "Private" version option in the community?

[image: readthedocs settings image]

- Public can be seen by anyone, including search bots
- Protected only shows through direct link
- Private mode tells me I have no permission to access my docs.

However, [RTD documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/privacy.html?highlight=privacy) states:

> #### Private
>
> Private objects are available only to people who have permissions to see them.

I'm working on something I want to make open source, but I'd rather keep it Private as I compose the documentation. However, I can't figure out how to give myself permissions to read the documentation in the Private version of the docs. I'm the maintainer, so I believe that's the most I can get.

**What's the point of the Private Version setting, is it private at all or just hidden? Am I missing something?**